# Powershell Invoke-Command with IP address instead of Hostname

Tags: powershell

I need to check existence of a specific service on a group of hosts by means of Invoke-Command. but i got the error mentioned that i can't use IP address in Invoke-Command. Following is snippet of my code :

```
`$Server_List = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Asset Discovery\Assets2.csv" | 
 select -ExpandProperty IP
 #Hash Tables
 $Installed=@{}
 Not_Installed=@{}


 foreach ($Computer in $Server_List) {
         
        #Check Wazuh existence block. 
         $Wazuh = $null
         $Wazuh = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {Get-Service -Name 
         "WazuhSvc"}     
  
         if ($Wazuh){
           #  Write-Host "Service $Wazuh found on $Computer" -ForegroundColor Yellow
              $Installed.Add("$Computer","Installed")
         }
    
         else{
  
              Write-Host "Service $Wazuh not found on $Computer." -ForegroundColor Red
              $Not_Installed.Add("$Computer","Not Installed")
                         
         }`
```

I've decided to convert IP addresses to Hostnames using "([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByAddress" but there is not any PTR record for some IPs.How can i run command on a remote host using IP address ?

Comment: Can you add your error message?

Comment: please post the FULL text of your error msg in your Question. **_my system will use an ipv4 address with the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet._**

Comment: There are some restrictions on using an IP Addreess instead of hostname. Check out the [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2) and [Remote Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-7.2) documentation.

Comment: here is the error i've got : 
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (192.168.50.56:String) [], 
 PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotUseIPAddress,PSSessionStateBroken

Answer (score 0):

I think You forgot to set the -delimiter parameter when You import-csv.
First line should look like this:

```
$Server_List = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Asset Discovery\Assets2.csv" -delimiter "," |select -ExpandProperty IP
```

Now Your $Server_List contains all IP as a list and You will be able to run the foreach loop

Comment: that's not the point . It works even without delimiter . here is the error i've got : + CategoryInfo : OpenError: (192.168.50.56:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotUseIPAddress,PSSessionStateBroken . It mentions exactly that it's not allowed to use ip address.

Comment: Try to add the remote server to Your trusted hosts at your local computer. this can be done by: winrm s winrm/config/client ‘@{TrustedHosts=”Remote ip”}

Comment: I just added remote hosts to "trusted hosts" getting same result .

Comment: You might need to set the Trusted hosts on the remote server too.